# Make Multiple points to detect colors from live camera

Tags: android, android-camera, color-picker, color-detection

Need to detect colors from multiple points on Live camera. the app on playstore having single point color detection.[Grab color](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loomatix.colorgrab&hl=en_IN)
[image: single point to detect colors]
 Right now i can able to detect color from single point on live camera. ex : point means yellow circle on above image. What i need is to make multiple Yellow circle points to detect color.
How to add multiple points on live camera?

Comment: Please expand on your question to including what you have and where exactly you need help.

Comment: thanks, right now i can able to detect color from single point on live camera. ex : point means yellow circle on above image. What i need is to make multiple Yellow circle points to detect color.

Answer (score 0):

The "Multi-ColorPicker" library should be able to help you add the features you desire.

Checkout it's Github [here](https://github.com/skydoves/Multi-ColorPicker)

Comment: Ok thanks, i am not sure how to add these features on live camera.